# Outlook stripping styles from <head>

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email

Using Outlook.com I've been using inspect element to see why some of my styles like for dark mode aren't working, in doing so I can't see any of my styles at all coming through. Even using a basic style with only one class I can't see it coming through at all. Weirdly though it works fine when I place the styles in the body, but then this breaks a lot of the other clients. Any ideas?

```
  <head>
    <title>{{StoreName}}</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark" />
    <meta name="supported-color-schemes" content="light dark" />
    <link
      rel="shortcut icon"
      type="image/x-icon"
      href="https://{{StoreUrl}}/static/Favicon/icon.ico"
    />
    <style>
      .dog {
        padding: 5px;
      }
    </style>
</head>
```

I've tried removing styles, moving them to the body, making sure my head tags are correct, searched through a lot of articles et.c

Comment: When you say "I place the styles in the body", do you mean you inlined them, or you literally moved the `<style>` block within `<body>`?

Answer (score 2):

Are you keeping the double accolade/curly braces in there when you test?

There is a bug specific to Outlook.com that removes all styles after double curly braces. See https://github.com/hteumeuleu/email-bugs/issues/92

It can also trigger when you have an @media block or similar that has two }} in a row, but separated only by spacing/line breaks, and a minifier brings them together. If you can't control the minifier, you would have to stop the style block and start another one before writing any more styles (or put the @media block at the end of your style block).

Comment: Hi, yes I have also come across this issue. I have managed to keep a space between the curly braces while minifying which seems to have sorted the issue. The other handlebars variables would be replaced before being sent. This was definitely pat of my issue but not completely, seems to be no rhyme or reason to if it allows my styles or not in the head

Comment: Just to confirm, we're talking about seeing the styles in the actual final email on Outlook.com, and not "my dark mode styles are there but aren't working"? Because dark mode is a whole separate issue

Comment: If they do work putting the styles in the body, it's not a bad thing to do that as well (so, literally copy, rather than cut and paste). That should not break other email clients, but of course test everything

Comment: So after much research I have discovered it was an issue with the email server in the end. However as soon as I fixed that I ran into the the double curly brace issue so thank you for bringing it up!