# Targeting Outlook.com with CSS / conditionals in 2022?

Tags: css, outlook, html-email

I have a huge issue specifically with the browser version of Outlook (webmail) when sending emails.

All the solutions that worked in the past are no longer viable in 2022:

```
[owa] .foo {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

```
[class="x_foo"] {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

I have also tried all kinds of conditional tags, but they just don't work in browser either:

```
<!--[if mso]>
    <style>
        .example-class {
            /* Outlook-specific CSS goes here. */
        }
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Is there any known hack to target Outlook in the browsers in 2022 (Outlook.com)?

Answer (score 1):

Outlook.com webmail can be targeted like so:

```
[class~="x_your-class-name"] {
  /* Replace this comment with your styles */
}
```

According to "How to target email" https://howtotarget.email/

> Outlook.com prefixes class names with x_ but doesn’t do this on
> attribute selectors. So  can be targeted
> with [class="x_your-class-name"] and it’ll only apply to Outlook.

There are other issues specific to Outlook webmail, so be sure to check this common one out first: [Outlook stripping styles from <head>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74360761/outlook-stripping-styles-from-head/74368838#74368838)